# Socket.io - Strategy for broadcasting to users of different permission levels

Tags: angularjs, node.js, laravel, socket.io

Using socket.io to broadcast events and data to other listeners is kind of straight forward, when everyone is allowed to see the data. But is there some strategy I can use when each user is only allowed to see data that belongs to them?

For example, we have a system of orders. On the dashboard, some users can see all the orders based on their access level. So if an order gets updated by one user, I could broadcast that event to all the other users without having to retrieve the new data for each window open on the dashboard, right?

So maybe an example would be something like `socket.send('ordersUpdated', data)` from the client side, in which I think the node server can catch it and emit the data to the other sockets listening in on that `ordersUpdated` event.

But what about cases where users can only see their own orders? I can't broadcast that same data to them because each user of this level can only see their own data. What if one of their orders is one that gets modified by a user that can see all the orders? Their dashboard would need up update too, but they can't receive that same broadcasted data.

Is there a particular way I should approach this? One idea, although not a good one I think, would be to just send an event saying that something updated, which will cause them to re-fetch the data from the server.

To provide more details, I'm also using Angular and Laravel.

Comment: `sockets`, on a programming level, are not `socket.io` related... I removed the tag. See the [tag:sockets] tag details for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use chat rooms to manage groups of users with a given level of access.  For example, you could have a series of rooms named by level of permission.  When a user connects to the server and authenticates who they are you could put them in whatever chat rooms they belong in (according to their permission level).  The highest level of permission (allowed to see all orders) might be called "all_orders".

Then, when a change to an order occurs, you broadcast it to everyone in all_orders and any other chat rooms that are consistent with the change.  You would also notify the user who is directly associated with the order.

The advantage of using chat rooms is that you use the built-in socket.io scheme for keeping track of groups of users and broadcasting to them.  The onus would still be on your server code to figure out which group of users should be notified about a given order, but socket.io would manage the mechanics of managing a group of users and broadcasting to them.  Another advantage of using chat rooms is when a user disconnects, socket.io automatically removes that socket from all associated chat rooms.  If you use you own data structure for the groups, you will have to remove a given socket anytime it connects to avoid memory leaks.